# Scale invariance of uniform distribution over $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

If we make a uniform distribution of points over $\mathbb R^2$ with 1 point on average per unit square. And we zoom far out and make a density plot (give a color to each cell according to how many Points it contains, normalized to average) and we zoom even farther out and do the same I expect it to have the same distribution. Is this true? What distribution is it? Is there a way to make precise and prove this scale inariance?

Comment: Although this is phrased fairly vaguely, I think I can guess what you mean, except for the phrase "normalized to average".  Can you explain that? $\qquad$

Comment: I just mean that the same color should correspond to the average number of Points in a cell when we scale the cell as we zoom

Comment: It appears to me that what you have in mind may be a Poisson process. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that what you have in mind is a Poisson process.  Two essential facts about the process described in your question are the following.

- Let $X$ be the number of sites falling within a particular region whose area is $a$.  Then $\operatorname{E}(X) = a.$
- If two regions do not intersect each other, then the numbers of sites falling within them are **independent** random variables.

From those facts it is possible to deduce that $\Pr(X = n) = \dfrac{a^n e^{-a}}{n!}$.

This discrete probability distribution is a Poisson distribution.