# Defining a uniform distribution of points in the plane

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1872794/21820), and was wondering what is the best way to describe a random distribution of points in the plane such that the expected number of points in any region of unit area is $c$, where $c$ is a given positive constant, and such that the number of points in every pair of disjoint regions are independent.
$\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}$

I can mimic the derivation of the Poisson distribution in the following manner:

1. Take any $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>c}\,\,.$ Partition each unit square of the plane into an $n \times n$ grid of square cells.
2. With probability $\lfrac{c}{n^2}$ put a point into each cell, distributed uniformly within the cell, independently of other cells.
3. Then every region comprising $n^2$ cells has expected number of points $c$.
4. Also every pair of disjoint regions have independent numbers of points.
5. Now if $n \to \infty$, I presume that this will more and more accurately resemble the desired distribution of points.

But I have no idea how to take such a limit, nor what the limit distribution is!. I suspect it might be important that the cells are getting smaller in both dimensions, but I don't know. (If each square is partitioned into $n$ horizontal rectangles instead, each rectangle comprising $1 \times n$ cells, and the probability changed to $\lfrac{c}{n}$, the number of points in two vertical regions each comprising $n^2 \times 1$ cells will not be independent. This dependence might not affect the final limiting distribution, if such a limit exists at all, but a priori it is not clear to me.)

So how can we rigorously define such a distribution, and is it really the limit of the above concept, in which case how do we rigorously define this limit?

Comment: Let us speak about $\mathbb{R}$. The same can be said about  $\mathbb{R}^2$.

It is not possible to speak theoretically, with Lebesgue measure (the usual measure $\lambda([a,b])=b-a$) of a uniform distribution of whole $\mathbb{R}$. What would then be the density ? A constant, of course... but which constant ? Any pdf $f(x)=a$ (with $a>0$ would give $\int f(x)dx=\infty$... contradiction. Same contradiction if $a=0$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Did you even read my question? I never once said anything about a uniform distribution over the whole plane.

Comment: All right, but dont' be aggressive. Let us say that I have misread your question. But are you adressing the question of simulation by pseudo random points ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: If you misread my question, just delete your comments and I'll delete mine. I never said anything about simulation either. I want to know if there is a mathematically rigorous way to define such a random distribution of points that satisfies the two properties that I specified. That's all. Whether or not it can be simulated only matters after we can show that such a distribution exists.

Comment: Let us close our discussion here.

Comment: Maybe a bit metaphorically, this is about $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ being independent random variables each with a uniform distribution on the whole plane $\mathbb R^2$, where $n$ is a sufficiently large infinite integer so that the expected number of observations $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ that fall within a region of unit area is $c$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: There is no such thing as a uniform distribution on the whole plane.....

Comment: @user21820 : Certainly according to the concepts currently prevailing, there is no such distribution, and accordingly I said "Perhaps a bit metaphorically."  I notice you didn't also tell me that there is no such thing as an infinite integer. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I didn't care about "infinite integer" because that's not really relevant to the question and because one might argue that infinite integers can be used in non-standard analysis. However, I'm certain that such a distribution of points as I've described **does exist**, which does not imply the existence of a uniform distribution on the plane.

Comment: Indeed, it exists and the distribution of the number of sites in every region of finite area is the Poisson distribution with expected value $c$ times the area of the region. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: That's an unproven claim. I too believe that but you're going to have to address my question to convince me. I want absolute rigour here, not hand-wavy intuition. =)

Comment: Rigor is found in my posted answer. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Don't be stubborn. I already pointed out in my comment which line of your answer is not rigorous. If you don't believe me, define the probability space rigorously and show me that it has the desired properties.

Comment: You claim to have mentioned some particular line in my answer?  Do you mean the part where you said " "We need a limit as $m\to\infty$." is totally unjustified."? $\qquad$

Comment: BTW I think the request for a first-order statement in the language of ZFC is silly. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes that line. And I didn't say you must give a first-order statement in ZFC. I just said that such would be counted as rigorous. In general, as long as every line is justified I'm fine. Yours doesn't meet that criterion.

Comment: Apparently you did make this distinction between horizontal and vertical.  But to say something is "crucial" about that is at best something you haven't established.   What is crucial about the division into $m$ parts contemplated in my posted answer is that it ought to remain true regardless of how the region is divided up into parts of equal sizes.  Making a big deal about horizontal-versus-vertical is concentrating on inessentials.  Maybe that's why I didn't notice on first reading that you were doing that. $\qquad$

Comment: For the record, WHICH "line" of my posting do you have a problem with? $\qquad$

Comment: Fine I retract my use of the word "crucial". I made a mistake in saying that because it felt crucial to me. The line of your answer that has a problem is "We need a limit as $m→∞$." This line does not justify the existence of a distribution with the desired properties. All your answer shows, which I already know, is that we know how to define a Poisson random variable, and its distribution is the limit of that of a sequence of Binomial distributions. This is logically very far from what I asked for.

Comment: You can construct the desired process more directly by dividing the plane into an infinite grid of unit squares.  Enumerate the squares and let $\{X_i\}$ be i.i.d. Poisson random variables of rate $\lambda = c$.  For each square $i$, given that $X_i=k$, independently and uniformly distribute $k$ points over that square.

Comment: @Michael: How do you prove that this has the desired properties?

Comment: @Shalop : To start and get insight, just take one such unit square as I describe above, take 2 disjoint measurable regions $A$ and $B$ of it, and let $C$ be the remainder of the unit square.  Let $N_A$, $N_B$, $N_C$ be the number of points in regions $A$, $B$, $C$.  Can you compute the joint mass function $P[N_A=a, N_B=b, N_C=c]$?   Or, for simplicity, just take $A$ and $A^c$ (where complement is in the unit square), and compute $$P[N_A=a, N_{A^c}= b] = P[\{X=a+b\} \cap \{\mbox{exactly $a$ go in region $A$}\}]$$  You can repeat for any number of disjoint measurable regions of the unit square.

Comment: @Micheal: Okay that works. In fact, your method of construction is the same as the one given in the first source I posted below.

Comment: @Michael: I've posted an answer based on your hint. Can you please help me check? In particular I don't think there is any easier way to go from the 1-square case to the general case.

Comment: @Shalop: My answer is completely elementary in the sense that it only requires basic measure theory. Since I didn't use Fourier transforms, did I make any mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to *Michael* and *Shalop* for the core ideas, here is a rigorous definition and proof.
$
\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}
\def\zz{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}
\def\pp{\mathbb{P}}
\def\ee{\mathbb{E}}
\def\ii{\mathbf{1}}
\def\wi{\subseteq}
\def\none{\varnothing}
\def\t{\text}
\def\lsum{{\large\sum}}
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

### Definition

> Let $S_{a,b} = [a,a+1) \times [b,b+1)$, for each $a,b \in \zz$.
>
> Let $X_{a,b} \sim \t{Pois}(c)$ independently for each $a,b \in \zz$.
>
> Let $P_{a,b}$ be a set of $X_{a,b}$ points distributed uniformly in $S_{a,b}$ independently for each $a,b \in \zz$.
>
> Let $P = \bigcup_{a,b\in\zz} P_{a,b}$.

### Theorem

> $\#(P \cap U) \sim \t{Pois}(c|U|)$ for any $U \wi \rr^2$ with finite measure.
>
> $\#(P \cap U),\#(P \cap V)$ are independent for any disjoint $U,V \wi \rr^2$ each with finite measure.

### Proof

For each measurable $R \wi \rr^2$, let $N_R = \#( P \cap R )$.

[First we prove the 1-square case.]

Take any $a,b \in \zz$ and disjoint measurable $Q,R \wi S_{a,b}$.

Let $x = 1-|Q|-|R|$ and $y = |Q|$ and $z = |R|$.

Given any $m,n \in \nn$:

$\pp( ⟨N_Q,N_R⟩ = ⟨m,n⟩ ) = \lsum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-c} \lfrac{c^{k+m+n}}{(k+m+n)!} \binom{k+m+n}{k,m,n} x^k y^m z^n$

$\ = e^{-c} \lfrac{c^{m+n}}{m!n!} y^m z^n \lsum_{k=0}^\infty \lfrac{(cx)^k}{k!}$ $= e^{-c} \lfrac{c^{m+n}}{m!n!} y^m z^n e^{cx}$ $= e^{-cy} \lfrac{(cy)^m}{m!} \ e^{-cz} \lfrac{(cz)^n}{n!}$.

$\pp(N_Q=m) = \pp(⟨N_Q,\none⟩ = ⟨m,0⟩) = e^{-cy} \lfrac{(cy)^m}{m!}$ and likewise $\pp(N_R=n) = e^{-cz} \lfrac{(cz)^n}{n!}$.

Therefore $N_Q,N_R$ are independent and $N_Q \sim \t{Pois}(c|Q|)$ and $N_R \sim \t{Pois}(c|R|)$.

[Now we prove the general case.]

Note that the 1-square case extends easily [by induction] to the finite-squares case.

For each measurable $R \wi \rr^2$, let $T_k = \bigcup_{a,b \in \{-k..k\}} S_{a,b}$ and $N_{R,k} = \#( P \cap R \cap T_k )$.

Take any disjoint measurable $U,V \wi \rr^2$ such that $|U|,|V|$ are finite.

Given any $m,n \in \nn$:

For $k \in \nn$ as $k \to \infty$:

$\pp( N_U \le m ) \approx \pp( N_{U,k} \le m )$   [by MCT for sets]

$\ = \pp( \t{Pois}(c|U \cap T_k|) \le m )$   [by the finite-squares case and sum of Poisson r.v.]

$\ \approx \pp( \t{Pois}(c|U|) \le m )$   [by MCT for sets]

$\pp( N_U \le m \land N_V \le n )$

$\ \approx \pp( N_{U,k} \le m \land N_{V,k} \le n )$   [by MCT for sets]

$\ = \lsum_{i=0}^m \lsum_{j=0}^n \pp( N_{U,k} = i \land N_{V,k} = j )$

$\ = \lsum_{i=0}^m \lsum_{j=0}^n \pp( N_{U,k} = i ) \ \pp( N_{V,k} = j )$   [by the finite-squares case]

$\ = \pp( N_{U,k} \le m ) \ \pp( N_{V,k} \le n )$

$\ \approx \pp( N_U \le m ) \ \pp( N_V \le n )$   [by MCT for sets].

Therefore $\pp( N_U \le m ) = \pp( \t{Pois}(c|U|) \le m )$

and $\pp( N_U \le m \land N_V \le n ) = \pp( N_U \le m ) \ \pp( N_V \le n )$.

Therefore $N_U \sim \t{Pois}(c|U|)$ and $N_U,N_V$ are independent.

### Notes

At all the marked points we are implicitly using MCT for sets, which states the following:

Take any set $T$ such that $|T|$ is finite, and any sequence $(S_k)_{k\in\nn}$ of measurable sets such that $S_k \wi T$ for every $k \in \nn$ and $S_k \to S$ monotonically as $k \to \infty$. Then $|S_k| \to |S|$ as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating certain things here. First of all you can just compute the joint distribution of $(N_Q, N_R, N_{S_{a,b} \backslash (Q \cup R)})$ which is more straightforward than writing out long summations. Secondly, yes it is true that an infinite sum of independent poisson random variables is itself poisson if the sum of parameters is finite. This can be shown first for finite sums which is easy by just considering two such variables and then using induction. Then for the infinite case, use the fact that almost sure convergence implies convergence in distribution.

Comment: @Shalop: There are two parts. The long summations in the second part are to deal with arbitrary measurable regions $U,V$, where we do not have the joint distribution. And yes do you have a reference for how to get the infinite case from the finite one? I'm not sure what you mean by almost sure convergence here. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I understand that there are two parts. I'm saying that for the first part, you can just compute the joint distribution of three disjoint things whose union is all of $S_{a,b}$ rather than just two things, to make your life easier. For the second part you can use the fact that if $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ is any measurable set then we have the almost sure equality $N_A = \sum_{a,b} N_{S_{a,b} \cap A}$ which is just an infinite sum of Poissons hence is Poisson assuming $\mu(A)< \infty$, as I said before.

Comment: @Shalop: Okay, I see what you mean for the first part. I still don't get what you mean by almost sure equality. Isn't $N_A = \sum_{a,b} N_{S_{a,b} \cap A}$ an exact equality by definition? And how exactly do we use that to get independence, which my second part proves?

Comment: Minor comment:  The $\{X_{a,b}\}$ variables should be [i.i.d.] Poisson, and the random placement of points in each square should be independent over squares.  I agree you can likely simplify.

Comment: If you re-index your squares $\{S_{a,b}\}$ into an ordered list $\{S_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and then take any disjoint subsets $U$ and $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$,  each with finite measure, you can define $N_U[k] = \sum_{i=1}^k N_{U \cap S_i}$ and $N_V[k] = \sum_{i=1}^k N_{V \cap S_i}$ (similar to the Shalop notation).  These are finite sums of mutually independent Poisson random variables. Also, $N_U[k] \nearrow N_U$ and $N_V[k] \nearrow N_V$ and for each pair of integers $(a,b)$ we get $$ P[N_U[k] \leq a]P[N_V[k]\leq b]=P[N_U[k] \leq a, N_V[k] \leq b]   \searrow P[N_U\leq a, N_V \leq b]$$.

Comment: @Michael: You are right. I accidentally forgot to state the independence of $X_{a,b}$ and the uniform placement. And I see the trick is to use the cdf instead of the pdf. Can I change my answer to use your approach? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user21820 : Yes you can change your answer if you like.

Comment: @Michael: Thank you! I think the use of MCT for measurable sets cannot be dispensed with. Though I'm now wondering whether the machinery I used in my approach can be easily formalized in standard probability theory or not.

Comment: @Shalop: I've updated my answer, though I decided not to use the joint density function because ultimately we still have to sum to recover the desired distribution, and it cancels in exactly the same way. Anyway thanks for your original answer and your feedback! =)

Answer (score 2):

There is one notable example of such a random collection of points in $\Bbb R^d$.

This example is the **Poisson Point Process**, also called the **Spatial Poisson Process**. This random set $N$ of points has the property that for any Borel set $B \subset \Bbb R^d$, we have that $N\cap B$ is distributed as a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda(B)$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure, and such that disjoint regions have independent numbers of points intersecting $N$.

If you're interested and want to know more about random point measures and Poisson Point Processes, you can see [the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Spatial_Poisson_point_process) and its sources therein.

The construction of such a random cloud of points can be done in great generality, for instance on abstract measure spaces (not just $\Bbb R^n$ with Lebesgue measure). However, such a construction uses the Kolmogorov Extension Theorem and I won't be bothered to write out the details here (although you may want to try it as an exercise). In $\Bbb R^2$ there might be a much simpler construction without using such powerful abstract machinery.

See [this PDF](https://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/math7880/S11/Chapters/Ch4.pdf) for a simple construction of the Poisson random measure using a method similar to yours. And see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/27tgatnaeehpwve/SpatialPoissonP.pdf?dl=0) for another (possibly unnecessarily convoluted, and rather poorly written) abstract construction using Kolmogorov Extension.

Comment: Indeed I want to see a rigorous definition of such an object as I've described in my question. What you describe as the spatial Poisson process does not answer my question because it's merely for a bounded region $B$ of the plane, according to the Wikipedia article you cited. I do not see how one can rigorously define the distribution of points for $B$ being the whole plane! Can it be done rigorously by the Kolmogorov extension theorem? I'm unfamiliar with that although I know some measure theory.

Comment: "Can it be done rigorously by the Kolmogorov extension theorem?" Yes.

Comment: "There are many examples of such random collections of points" Actually, if one assumes that "the expected number of points in any (measurable) region" is c times the area of the region, "where c is a given positive constant, and such that the number of points in every pair of disjoint (measurable) regions are independent" there is only one, which is the homogenous Poisson point process you describe afterwards.

Comment: @Did: fixed, thanks.

Comment: @user21820: It's not just for a bounded region, it's for any Borel measurable set in $\Bbb R^2$, including $\Bbb R^2$ itself.

Comment: Well the wikipedia page didn't say so. Anyway from glancing through the pdf you cited, it seems that the trick is to first prove that we can define such a distribution on a finite measure space, and then extend to the σ-finite measure space. But I don't understand most of it, and it mentions Fourier transform uniqueness; is there an elementary way?

Comment: @user21820: I don't know any.

Comment: Oh well okay then thanks! I was hoping there was an elementary way but never mind. I also note that it seems the trick is not to define a random variable whose support is all possible sets of points in the plane, but to define one positive integer random variable for each set such that they have the desired properties.

Comment: @user21820: Also, you seem to be misunderstanding the Wikipedia page. It is saying that the quantity $N(B)$ is defined for bounded sets $B$ contained in $\Bbb R^n$; that doesn't mean that our random set is contained in some bounded set $B$.

Comment: Ah yes I misread the article; thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @user21820: Yes that is a key idea in both constructions discussed above.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to accept my answer if it is correct, only because it is elementary, but anyway I already upvoted yours last time. =)

Comment: @user21820: No problem. I don't mind in any case.

Answer (score -2):

Say the expected number of sites in a given region is $c$; divide the region into $m$ parts.  Approximate the desired distribution by saying you put a site into each part with probability $c/m$.  This forbids the improbable event of more than one site in one of those $m$ parts, so it's not exact.  We need a limit as $m\to\infty$.

The probability that the number (capital) $X$ of sites in the region is (lower-case) $x$ is
\begin{align}
\Pr(X=x) & = \binom m x \left( \frac c m \right)^x \left( 1 - \frac c m \right)^{m-x} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{m(m-1)(m-2)(m-3)\cdots(m-x+1)}{x!} \cdot \frac{c^x}{m^x} \cdot \left( 1-\frac c m \right)^m \left( 1- \frac c m \right)^{-x} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{m(m-1)(m-2)(m-3)\cdots(m-x+1)}{m^x} \cdot \frac{c^x}{x!} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac c m \right)^m \left( 1 - \frac c m \right)^{-x} \\[10pt]
& = \underbrace{\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)(m-3)\cdots(m-x+1)}{m^x}}_{\text{This } \rightarrow \, 1} \cdot \frac{c^x}{x!} \cdot \underbrace{\left( 1 - \frac c m \right)^m}_{\text{This }\rightarrow\, e^{-c}}\  \underbrace{\left( 1 - \frac c m \right)^{-x}}_{\text{This }\rightarrow \,1} \\[15pt]
& \to \frac{c^x e^{-c}}{x!} \qquad \text{as } m\to\infty.
\end{align}

(Notice that the factor $\dfrac{c^x}{x!}$ does not change as $m\to\infty$, so its limit is not problematic (to say the least).)

In other words in the limit, $X$ has a Poisson distribution with expected value $c$.

Comment: Yes I know this **so-called** derivation, but as I made very clear in my question, it's not rigorous. What does the limit even mean for the distribution, and why should the limit give the desired properties? I also stated very clearly that the way of dividing the regions matters, so your answer isn't addressing any part of my question at all. Sorry.

Comment: @user21820 : Perhaps you can clarify your question. $\qquad$

Comment: Which part of my question is not clear? I showed that if you divide in the wrong way, the second desired condition is not satisfied by any of the approximating distributions, and so there's no reason the limit would either (whatever the limit might be). The more pertinent problem is that the limit of such a concept is not even well-defined. If you can show how to write down an explicit first-order statement in the language of ZFC that defines such a distribution, it would count as a rigorous definition. As for your answer, "We need a limit as $m→∞$." is totally unjustified.

Comment: @user21820 : I believe you're mistaken.  You did not show that if you divide in the "wrong" way, something goes wrong.  Your division of each square into $n$ thin rectangles works just as well as any other division of plane regions into parts: You're dividing each square into $n$ (not $n^2$ parts, each with probability $c/n$ (not $c/n^2$) of containing one site, and with the numbers of sites in non-intersecting parts being independent.  (Your assertion that they will not be independent is simply erroneous.) $\qquad$

Comment: I'm not mistaken about the non-independence (and I did specify those changed partition size and probability in my question). If one piece has $n$ points, all $(n-1)$ other pieces must each have $0$ points with probability $1$. That said, it may not affect the limiting distribution (but as I said one has to first define what such a limit means), but you'll have to prove it rigorously.

Comment: You divide the unit square into $n$ rectangles, each $1/n$ by $1$.  They don't intersect.  The number of sites falling in each such rectangle is $1$ with probability $c/n$, and those numbers are independent.  The expected number of sites in the whole square is $c$.  How is it that you claim to have shown somehow that they are not independent? $\qquad$

Comment: I said the division was into **horizontal** rectangles and that two disjoint **vertical** regions have non-independent counts. One might object that this cuts into the rectangles but it is not clear that the issue goes away in the 'limit'. The whole point is that without a rigorous definition of the limit, there's nothing one can say about which division works.

Comment: I had in mind that regardless of how one divides the region into $m$ parts, the conclusions hold. $\qquad$

Comment: That would be a strong claim, and it would be excellent if it can be proven rigorously. It feels true (if the unit squares are fixed beforehand and cut up into $n$ pieces for each approximation), but I'd be happy to see even one fixed method of cutting that can be shown to give the desired properties.